# Does Node's crypto.createHmac() function supply an initialization vector?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, hmac

In using [Node's HMAC](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhmac_algorithm_key), I am trying to figure out of if this is sufficient.  I.E. the IV is supplied internally:

```
let crypto = require('crypto');
let hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret);
hash.update('the text to be signed');
let hmac = hash.digest();
```

Or, if I need to do this instead.  I.E. I need to supply and keep track of the IV:

```
let crypto = require('crypto');
let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
let hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret);
hash.update(iv);
hash.update('the text to be signed');
let hmac = hash.digest();
```

I did attempt to read the [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/aea7269c45f91fd983e8ca91fddd4021fc40d099/lib/crypto.js) but I'm not familiar enough with Node and Javascript to follow it.

Comment: HMAC does not make use of an IV and the node.js implementation follows that specification. An IV is used for block cipher modes of operation which has nothing to do with HMAC. Why do you need an IV for HMAC? What kind of security property are you hoping for?

Comment: I am using at as a digital signature.  "HMAC does not make use of an IV" - thank you for correcting my bad assumption.

Comment: HMAC also doesn't provide a digital signature functionality. Since the secret must be shared between sender and receiver, there is no way for anybody to distinguish which party "signed" some message which is what signatures are supposed to do.

Comment: Sorry, digital signature may be the wrong terminology.  I mean how it's used for example with JWT: https://jwt.io.